# Setting up start up page/component in Angular 8 but error "The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests"

Tags: angular8

I want to set login component as a startup component in Angular8. I have routing file where routing of all component is placed. But whenever I implemented the below changes It gives an error.

Previous When It was working fine with default component of Dashboard

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
```

when I replaced login with dashboard.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
```

It shows below error.

> Error: System.TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period